# Replacing multiple characters at once

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser, error-000539

I have a problem with replacing in field calculator.
For some reason my Python parser is not working. So I'm going to use VB and having tonns of this

```
Replace([field],"x","y") 
Replace([field],"z","a")
Replace([field],"1","2")
.
.
.
.
Replace([field],"g","j")
```

I would like to make all this into 1 line script. How to combine all of this?

Comment: I'm assuming that you are using the ArcGIS Field Calculator so I'm going to set tags for that.  What do your current code block and expression look like?

Comment: It's difficult to believe that Python stopped working, since ArcGIS geoprocessing  would not function without it. Instead of soliciting help with a work-around, please [Edit] the question to address the root issue

Comment: reason is when i use this on python parser !field!.replace() it doesnt work and in the geoprocessing result: Error 000539: syntax error: EOL while scanning string literal (<expression>, line 1) BTW im not an expert just trying to translate characters with field calculator and thanks for your help

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: I wouldn't expect "!field!.replace" to work, but if you use the pre-script code block to define a function, "fixString (!field!)" should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to *embed* function calls like this:

```
Replace(  Replace([field],"x","y"),  "z","a")
```

You should be able to apply functions to the results of other function calls as many times as you like.